# Clojure:riemann.streams$smap$stream IllegalArgumentException: Key must be integer

Tags: clojure, riemann

I have a clojure code(riemann) to send an email if certain condition was met. I am facing some issue while passing the event to riemann server.

**Riemann code**

```
(let [email (mailer {"......"})]

  (streams
    (where (service "system_log")

        (by :RefNo
         (smap
          (fn [events]
           (let [count-of-failures (count (filter #(= "Failed" (:Status %)) events))]        
              (assoc (first events)
                :status "Failure"
                 :metric  count-of-failures 
                 :total-fail (>= count-of-failures 2))))

          (where (and (= (:status event) "Failure")
                      (:total-fail event))

            (email "XXXXX@gmail.com"))prn)))))
```

**O/P in riemann server**

```
WARN [2015-11-18 05:24:49,596] defaultEventExecutorGroup-2-2 - riemann.streams - riemann.streams$smap$stream__3695@7addde9e threw
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Key must be integer
        at clojure.lang.APersistentVector.assoc(APersistentVector.java:335)
        at clojure.lang.APersistentVector.assoc(APersistentVector.java:18)
```

Update 2:

I simply changed the smap to sreduce. How I should update, since I am newbie to this I am little bit confused about altering the code as per your suggestion

```
(let [email (mailer {"......"})]

      (streams
        (where (service "system_log")

            (by :RefNo
             (sreduce
              (fn [events]
               (let [count-of-failures (count (filter #(= "Failed" (:Status %)) events))]        
                  (assoc (first events)
                    :status "Failure"
                     :metric  count-of-failures 
                     :total-fail (>= count-of-failures 2))))

              (where (and (= (:status event) "Failure")
                          (:total-fail event))

                (email "XXXXX@gmail.com"))prn)))))
```

**Update 3:**

I have updated my code using `coalesce` and `smap` has its child. Now its not showing any error but email didn't get triggered. I am getting `count-of-failures` as `0`. I guess `count function` is not working.

```
(let [email (mailer {"......"})]

          (streams
            (where (service "system_log")

                (by :RefNo
                 (coalesce
                   (smap
                  (fn [events]
                   (let [count-of-failures (count (filter #(= "Failed" (:status %)) events))]        
                      (assoc (first events)
                        :status "Failure"
                         :metric  count-of-failures 
                         :total-fail (>= count-of-failures 2))))

                  (where (and (= (:status event) "Failure")
                              (:total-fail event))

                    (email "XXXXX@gmail.com"))))prn))))
```

Answer (score 1):

Off the top of my hat, `by` accepts a vector not a symbol:

```
(by [:Refno] ...
```

As a side note, I recommend using REPL (e.g. https://github.com/aphyr/riemann/wiki/playing-with-the-REPL) so you can build your stream processing gradually while testing functions in the REPL. It worked great for me.

Update: I'm also not sure if you shouldn't nest the where inside `smap` because you're assigning "Failure" but the `where` runs in parallel to `smap` so unless I'm missing something, I think it won't see it.

Update 2: I've ran it through the REPL connected to Riemann like this:

```
(require '[riemann.streams :refer :all])
(def f (stream
        (where (service "system_log")
               (by :RefNo
                   (smap
                    (fn [events]
                      (let [count-of-failures (count (filter #(= "Failed" (:Status %)) events))]
                        (prn events)
                        (assoc (first events)
                               :status "Failure"
                               :metric  count-of-failures 
                               :total-fail (>= count-of-failures 2))))

                    #_(where (and (= (:status event) "Failure")
                                  (:total-fail event)))
                    prn)))))
(f {:RefNo 4444 :service "system_log" :status "Failed"})
```

It produces the same error that you've got. The error is there because you're assuming that the function passed to `smap` receives a list of events. It doesn't, it receives a single event (see the `prn` there). Calling `first` on a hashmap produces a vector, then trying to `assoc` using a symbol as a key gives you the error because vectors support only integers.

You cannot count failures this way just like you wouldn't use a regular `map` in Clojure for this purpose because you need past events.

Here's what I think might be compatible with your smap example.

Either:

1. Use coalesce http://riemann.io/api/riemann.streams.html#var-coalesce and smap as its child; I think smap will receive a list of events just like you wanted originally. I haven't tried it but there's no reason it shouldn't work.
2. You can control the time window you need (let's say max 2 failures per hour) by sending events with 1 hour TTL and querying the index within the stream. Here's a complete example: http://riemann.io/howto.html#query-the-index-from-within-a-stream

Apart from the that, I believe `:Status` should be in lower case. I hope it helps.

Comment: I have updated my code `(by [:Refno]`, but still I am getting the same error. Do I need to replace the `smap` .

Comment: By replacing `smap` with `sreduce` do I need keep `(by [:Refno]` as it is or I need to remove the `[]` from it.

Comment: It *seems* to work with a single symbol so maybe the function handles this case. I've used a vector because this is how I have understood the reference. But if it works, it works.

Comment: I have replaced `sreduce` in the place of `smap`. I tried removing the` [ ] `and tried without removing the `[ ]` for both cases I am getting this error. `"wrong number of argument(2) passed"`. I couldn't figure out the exact solution

Comment: Without seeing the code my guess is the function you're passing to `sreduce` has an incorrect signature. It should take two arguments just like for `reduce`. http://riemann.io/api/riemann.streams.html#var-sreduce

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95605/discussion-between-mangoski-and-marcin-bilski).

Comment: I have updated my code with coalesce now its not showing any error as before but email didn't get triggered.

Comment: 1. Have you fixed `:Status` and the position of where? 2. When you put prn inside `smap` (as one of its children) what does it print out?

Comment: 1. Yes I have fixed the `:Status` and where I need to change the position of `where` .  2. It prints the event as it is i can see `count-of-failure` field as `zero`. can you please verify my `updated code 3` in the question and suggest your modification.

Comment: It's really hard to tell like this what may be wrong. There are just too many factors, TTL etc. Have you tried the REPL? You can dissect the pipeline and build it gradually, checking your assumptions along the way. Also see info about testing Riemann. Just trying out to fix it by guessing is not a very productive use of either your or mine time.

Comment: Look at my code (Update 2), it's precisely what you need to evaluate the pipeline in the REPL. It's much faster than reloading Riemann (or restarting it!) everytime you change something, sending events and looking at output.